# List of iOS font names

Tags: ios, fonts

If you look at this nice list of preinstalled fonts that Apple compiled, you'll notice 2 things missing.

[iOS and macOS System Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/#preinstalled)

1. Visual representation of the font. (would be nice, Apple)
2. More importantly, the actual font name that you need to use.

As an example, in Xcode/Swift if I want to use Apple SD Gothic Neo Heavy I can't use:

```
contactNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo Heavy", size: 13)
```

I would have to use:

```
contactNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Heavy", size: 13)
```

Just wanted to see if anyone has a link that shows these names, or otherwise, what the best practice is for easily finding them.

I apologize that my question is not strictly code related. This is my first Stack Overflow question, and I wish it could be more technical, but I think the answer to this could be helpful to people, including myself.
Thanks all.

Comment: Is there an answer which is acceptable to you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can print out all fonts and families available using this code:

```
    for family in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("family:", family)
        for font in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
            print("font:", font)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

By modifying the print statements using the for loops in the other answers, I made an extension of UIFont that allows you to access the font name string using the rawValue of an enum.

```
let myNewFont = UIFont(name: UIFont.nameOf.Thonburi_Light.rawValue, size: 30)!

extension UIFont {
public enum nameOf: String {
    case Copperplate_Light = "Copperplate-Light"
    case Copperplate = "Copperplate"
    case Copperplate_Bold = "Copperplate-Bold"
    case AppleSDGothicNeo_Thin = "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin"
    case AppleSDGothicNeo_Light = "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light"
    case AppleSDGothicNeo_Regular = "AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular"
    case AppleSDGothicNeo_Bold = "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold"
    case AppleSDGothicNeo_SemiBold = "AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold"
    case AppleSDGothicNeo_UltraLight = "AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight"
    case AppleSDGothicNeo_Medium = "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium"
    case Thonburi = "Thonburi"
    case Thonburi_Light = "Thonburi-Light"
    case Thonburi_Bold = "Thonburi-Bold"
    case GillSans_Italic = "GillSans-Italic"
    case GillSans_SemiBold = "GillSans-SemiBold"
    case GillSans_UltraBold = "GillSans-UltraBold"
    case GillSans_Light = "GillSans-Light"
    case GillSans_Bold = "GillSans-Bold"
    case GillSans = "GillSans"
    case GillSans_SemiBoldItalic = "GillSans-SemiBoldItalic"
    case GillSans_BoldItalic = "GillSans-BoldItalic"
    case GillSans_LightItalic = "GillSans-LightItalic"
    case MarkerFelt_Thin = "MarkerFelt-Thin"
    case MarkerFelt_Wide = "MarkerFelt-Wide"
    case HiraMaruProN_W4 = "HiraMaruProN-W4"
    case CourierNewPS_ItalicMT = "CourierNewPS-ItalicMT"
    case CourierNewPSMT = "CourierNewPSMT"
    case CourierNewPS_BoldItalicMT = "CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT"
    case CourierNewPS_BoldMT = "CourierNewPS-BoldMT"
    case KohinoorTelugu_Regular = "KohinoorTelugu-Regular"
    case KohinoorTelugu_Medium = "KohinoorTelugu-Medium"
    case KohinoorTelugu_Light = "KohinoorTelugu-Light"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_Heavy = "AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_MediumItalic = "AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_Regular = "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_UltraLightItalic = "AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLightItalic"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_Medium = "AvenirNextCondensed-Medium"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_HeavyItalic = "AvenirNextCondensed-HeavyItalic"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_DemiBoldItalic = "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_Bold = "AvenirNextCondensed-Bold"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_DemiBold = "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_BoldItalic = "AvenirNextCondensed-BoldItalic"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_Italic = "AvenirNextCondensed-Italic"
    case AvenirNextCondensed_UltraLight = "AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLight"
    case TamilSangamMN = "TamilSangamMN"
    case TamilSangamMN_Bold = "TamilSangamMN-Bold"
    case HelveticaNeue_UltraLightItalic = "HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic"
    case HelveticaNeue_Medium = "HelveticaNeue-Medium"
    case HelveticaNeue_MediumItalic = "HelveticaNeue-MediumItalic"
    case HelveticaNeue_UltraLight = "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight"
    case HelveticaNeue_Italic = "HelveticaNeue-Italic"
    case HelveticaNeue_Light = "HelveticaNeue-Light"
    case HelveticaNeue_ThinItalic = "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic"
    case HelveticaNeue_LightItalic = "HelveticaNeue-LightItalic"
    case HelveticaNeue_Bold = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
    case HelveticaNeue_Thin = "HelveticaNeue-Thin"
    case HelveticaNeue_CondensedBlack = "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack"
    case HelveticaNeue = "HelveticaNeue"
    case HelveticaNeue_CondensedBold = "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold"
    case HelveticaNeue_BoldItalic = "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic"
    case TimesNewRomanPS_ItalicMT = "TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT"
    case TimesNewRomanPS_BoldItalicMT = "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT"
    case TimesNewRomanPS_BoldMT = "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT"
    case TimesNewRomanPSMT = "TimesNewRomanPSMT"
    case Georgia_BoldItalic = "Georgia-BoldItalic"
    case Georgia_Italic = "Georgia-Italic"
    case Georgia = "Georgia"
    case Georgia_Bold = "Georgia-Bold"
    case SinhalaSangamMN_Bold = "SinhalaSangamMN-Bold"
    case SinhalaSangamMN = "SinhalaSangamMN"
    case ArialRoundedMTBold = "ArialRoundedMTBold"
    case Kailasa_Bold = "Kailasa-Bold"
    case Kailasa = "Kailasa"
    case KohinoorDevanagari_Regular = "KohinoorDevanagari-Regular"
    case KohinoorDevanagari_Light = "KohinoorDevanagari-Light"
    case KohinoorDevanagari_Semibold = "KohinoorDevanagari-Semibold"
    case KohinoorBangla_Regular = "KohinoorBangla-Regular"
    case KohinoorBangla_Semibold = "KohinoorBangla-Semibold"
    case KohinoorBangla_Light = "KohinoorBangla-Light"
    case NotoSansOriya_Bold = "NotoSansOriya-Bold"
    case NotoSansOriya = "NotoSansOriya"
    case ChalkboardSE_Bold = "ChalkboardSE-Bold"
    case ChalkboardSE_Light = "ChalkboardSE-Light"
    case ChalkboardSE_Regular = "ChalkboardSE-Regular"
    case NotoSansKannada_Bold = "NotoSansKannada-Bold"
    case NotoSansKannada_Light = "NotoSansKannada-Light"
    case NotoSansKannada_Regular = "NotoSansKannada-Regular"
    case AppleColorEmoji = "AppleColorEmoji"
    case PingFangTC_Regular = "PingFangTC-Regular"
    case PingFangTC_Thin = "PingFangTC-Thin"
    case PingFangTC_Medium = "PingFangTC-Medium"
    case PingFangTC_Semibold = "PingFangTC-Semibold"
    case PingFangTC_Light = "PingFangTC-Light"
    case PingFangTC_Ultralight = "PingFangTC-Ultralight"
    case GeezaPro_Bold = "GeezaPro-Bold"
    case GeezaPro = "GeezaPro"
    case DamascusBold = "DamascusBold"
    case DamascusLight = "DamascusLight"
    case Damascus = "Damascus"
    case DamascusMedium = "DamascusMedium"
    case DamascusSemiBold = "DamascusSemiBold"
    case Noteworthy_Bold = "Noteworthy-Bold"
    case Noteworthy_Light = "Noteworthy-Light"
    case Avenir_Oblique = "Avenir-Oblique"
    case Avenir_HeavyOblique = "Avenir-HeavyOblique"
    case Avenir_Heavy = "Avenir-Heavy"
    case Avenir_BlackOblique = "Avenir-BlackOblique"
    case Avenir_BookOblique = "Avenir-BookOblique"
    case Avenir_Roman = "Avenir-Roman"
    case Avenir_Medium = "Avenir-Medium"
    case Avenir_Black = "Avenir-Black"
    case Avenir_Light = "Avenir-Light"
    case Avenir_MediumOblique = "Avenir-MediumOblique"
    case Avenir_Book = "Avenir-Book"
    case Avenir_LightOblique = "Avenir-LightOblique"
    case KohinoorGujarati_Light = "KohinoorGujarati-Light"
    case KohinoorGujarati_Bold = "KohinoorGujarati-Bold"
    case KohinoorGujarati_Regular = "KohinoorGujarati-Regular"
    case DiwanMishafi = "DiwanMishafi"
    case AcademyEngravedLetPlain = "AcademyEngravedLetPlain"
    case PartyLetPlain = "PartyLetPlain"
    case Futura_CondensedExtraBold = "Futura-CondensedExtraBold"
    case Futura_Medium = "Futura-Medium"
    case Futura_Bold = "Futura-Bold"
    case Futura_CondensedMedium = "Futura-CondensedMedium"
    case Futura_MediumItalic = "Futura-MediumItalic"
    case ArialHebrew_Bold = "ArialHebrew-Bold"
    case ArialHebrew_Light = "ArialHebrew-Light"
    case ArialHebrew = "ArialHebrew"
    case Farah = "Farah"
    case MuktaMahee_Light = "MuktaMahee-Light"
    case MuktaMahee_Bold = "MuktaMahee-Bold"
    case MuktaMahee_Regular = "MuktaMahee-Regular"
    case NotoSansMyanmar_Regular = "NotoSansMyanmar-Regular"
    case NotoSansMyanmar_Bold = "NotoSansMyanmar-Bold"
    case NotoSansMyanmar_Light = "NotoSansMyanmar-Light"
    case Arial_BoldMT = "Arial-BoldMT"
    case Arial_BoldItalicMT = "Arial-BoldItalicMT"
    case Arial_ItalicMT = "Arial-ItalicMT"
    case ArialMT = "ArialMT"
    case Chalkduster = "Chalkduster"
    case Kefa_Regular = "Kefa-Regular"
    case HoeflerText_Italic = "HoeflerText-Italic"
    case HoeflerText_Black = "HoeflerText-Black"
    case HoeflerText_Regular = "HoeflerText-Regular"
    case HoeflerText_BlackItalic = "HoeflerText-BlackItalic"
    case Optima_ExtraBlack = "Optima-ExtraBlack"
    case Optima_BoldItalic = "Optima-BoldItalic"
    case Optima_Italic = "Optima-Italic"
    case Optima_Regular = "Optima-Regular"
    case Optima_Bold = "Optima-Bold"
    case Galvji_Bold = "Galvji-Bold"
    case Galvji = "Galvji"
    case Palatino_Italic = "Palatino-Italic"
    case Palatino_Roman = "Palatino-Roman"
    case Palatino_BoldItalic = "Palatino-BoldItalic"
    case Palatino_Bold = "Palatino-Bold"
    case MalayalamSangamMN_Bold = "MalayalamSangamMN-Bold"
    case MalayalamSangamMN = "MalayalamSangamMN"
    case AlNile = "AlNile"
    case AlNile_Bold = "AlNile-Bold"
    case LaoSangamMN = "LaoSangamMN"
    case BradleyHandITCTT_Bold = "BradleyHandITCTT-Bold"
    case HiraMinProN_W3 = "HiraMinProN-W3"
    case HiraMinProN_W6 = "HiraMinProN-W6"
    case PingFangHK_Medium = "PingFangHK-Medium"
    case PingFangHK_Thin = "PingFangHK-Thin"
    case PingFangHK_Regular = "PingFangHK-Regular"
    case PingFangHK_Ultralight = "PingFangHK-Ultralight"
    case PingFangHK_Semibold = "PingFangHK-Semibold"
    case PingFangHK_Light = "PingFangHK-Light"
    case Helvetica_Oblique = "Helvetica-Oblique"
    case Helvetica_BoldOblique = "Helvetica-BoldOblique"
    case Helvetica = "Helvetica"
    case Helvetica_Light = "Helvetica-Light"
    case Helvetica_Bold = "Helvetica-Bold"
    case Helvetica_LightOblique = "Helvetica-LightOblique"
    case Courier_BoldOblique = "Courier-BoldOblique"
    case Courier_Oblique = "Courier-Oblique"
    case Courier = "Courier"
    case Courier_Bold = "Courier-Bold"
    case Cochin_Italic = "Cochin-Italic"
    case Cochin_Bold = "Cochin-Bold"
    case Cochin = "Cochin"
    case Cochin_BoldItalic = "Cochin-BoldItalic"
    case TrebuchetMS_Bold = "TrebuchetMS-Bold"
    case TrebuchetMS_Italic = "TrebuchetMS-Italic"
    case Trebuchet_BoldItalic = "Trebuchet-BoldItalic"
    case TrebuchetMS = "TrebuchetMS"
    case DevanagariSangamMN = "DevanagariSangamMN"
    case DevanagariSangamMN_Bold = "DevanagariSangamMN-Bold"
    case Rockwell_Italic = "Rockwell-Italic"
    case Rockwell_Regular = "Rockwell-Regular"
    case Rockwell_Bold = "Rockwell-Bold"
    case Rockwell_BoldItalic = "Rockwell-BoldItalic"
    case SnellRoundhand = "SnellRoundhand"
    case SnellRoundhand_Bold = "SnellRoundhand-Bold"
    case SnellRoundhand_Black = "SnellRoundhand-Black"
    case ZapfDingbatsITC = "ZapfDingbatsITC"
    case BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT_Bold = "BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Bold"
    case BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT_BookIta = "BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-BookIta"
    case BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT_Book = "BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Book"
    case Verdana_Italic = "Verdana-Italic"
    case Verdana = "Verdana"
    case Verdana_Bold = "Verdana-Bold"
    case Verdana_BoldItalic = "Verdana-BoldItalic"
    case AmericanTypewriter_CondensedBold = "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold"
    case AmericanTypewriter_Condensed = "AmericanTypewriter-Condensed"
    case AmericanTypewriter_CondensedLight = "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight"
    case AmericanTypewriter = "AmericanTypewriter"
    case AmericanTypewriter_Bold = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
    case AmericanTypewriter_Semibold = "AmericanTypewriter-Semibold"
    case AmericanTypewriter_Light = "AmericanTypewriter-Light"
    case AvenirNext_Medium = "AvenirNext-Medium"
    case AvenirNext_DemiBoldItalic = "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic"
    case AvenirNext_DemiBold = "AvenirNext-DemiBold"
    case AvenirNext_HeavyItalic = "AvenirNext-HeavyItalic"
    case AvenirNext_Regular = "AvenirNext-Regular"
    case AvenirNext_Italic = "AvenirNext-Italic"
    case AvenirNext_MediumItalic = "AvenirNext-MediumItalic"
    case AvenirNext_UltraLightItalic = "AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic"
    case AvenirNext_BoldItalic = "AvenirNext-BoldItalic"
    case AvenirNext_Heavy = "AvenirNext-Heavy"
    case AvenirNext_Bold = "AvenirNext-Bold"
    case AvenirNext_UltraLight = "AvenirNext-UltraLight"
    case Baskerville_SemiBoldItalic = "Baskerville-SemiBoldItalic"
    case Baskerville_SemiBold = "Baskerville-SemiBold"
    case Baskerville_BoldItalic = "Baskerville-BoldItalic"
    case Baskerville = "Baskerville"
    case Baskerville_Bold = "Baskerville-Bold"
    case Baskerville_Italic = "Baskerville-Italic"
    case KhmerSangamMN = "KhmerSangamMN"
    case Didot_Bold = "Didot-Bold"
    case Didot = "Didot"
    case Didot_Italic = "Didot-Italic"
    case SavoyeLetPlain = "SavoyeLetPlain"
    case BodoniOrnamentsITCTT = "BodoniOrnamentsITCTT"
    case Symbol = "Symbol"
    case Charter_BlackItalic = "Charter-BlackItalic"
    case Charter_Bold = "Charter-Bold"
    case Charter_Roman = "Charter-Roman"
    case Charter_Black = "Charter-Black"
    case Charter_BoldItalic = "Charter-BoldItalic"
    case Charter_Italic = "Charter-Italic"
    case Menlo_BoldItalic = "Menlo-BoldItalic"
    case Menlo_Bold = "Menlo-Bold"
    case Menlo_Italic = "Menlo-Italic"
    case Menlo_Regular = "Menlo-Regular"
    case NotoNastaliqUrdu = "NotoNastaliqUrdu"
    case NotoNastaliqUrdu_Bold = "NotoNastaliqUrdu-Bold"
    case BodoniSvtyTwoSCITCTT_Book = "BodoniSvtyTwoSCITCTT-Book"
    case DINAlternate_Bold = "DINAlternate-Bold"
    case Papyrus_Condensed = "Papyrus-Condensed"
    case Papyrus = "Papyrus"
    case HiraginoSans_W3 = "HiraginoSans-W3"
    case HiraginoSans_W6 = "HiraginoSans-W6"
    case HiraginoSans_W7 = "HiraginoSans-W7"
    case PingFangSC_Medium = "PingFangSC-Medium"
    case PingFangSC_Semibold = "PingFangSC-Semibold"
    case PingFangSC_Light = "PingFangSC-Light"
    case PingFangSC_Ultralight = "PingFangSC-Ultralight"
    case PingFangSC_Regular = "PingFangSC-Regular"
    case PingFangSC_Thin = "PingFangSC-Thin"
    case MyanmarSangamMN = "MyanmarSangamMN"
    case MyanmarSangamMN_Bold = "MyanmarSangamMN-Bold"
    case AppleSymbols = "AppleSymbols"
    case Zapfino = "Zapfino"
    case BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT_BookIt = "BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-BookIt"
    case BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT_Book = "BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Book"
    case BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT_Bold = "BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Bold"
    case EuphemiaUCAS = "EuphemiaUCAS"
    case EuphemiaUCAS_Italic = "EuphemiaUCAS-Italic"
    case EuphemiaUCAS_Bold = "EuphemiaUCAS-Bold"
    case DINCondensed_Bold = "DINCondensed-Bold"
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I did a Google search and found a list [here](https://iosfontlist.com/). It seems to be what you are looking for, it has the visual representation, and should work with Xcode.

Comment: It's unfortunate that it seems they stopped updating it, and it would be nice if they offered the name and codeName in separate columns rather than changing it when you click on it, but this is pretty good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open **Font Book** application, find your font, select and switch to **font info preview mode** ( **i** button on topbar) and use the **PostScript** name of the font.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all available iOS fonts

```
        let familyNames = UIFont.familyNames

        for family in familyNames {

            print("Family name " + family)

            let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)

            for font in fontNames {
                print("    Font name: " + font)
            }
        }
```